# Is it safe to store pair on local storage for signing transaction?

Tags: subxt

I'm trying to use subxt in my yew front end app.

```
let pair = Pair::from_phrase(&"mnemonic".to_string(), Some("password"))?;
```

As I can't use polkadot extension for signing transaction, is it safe to store mnemonic in local storage than using the password (without storing password in local storage) for signing transaction.

How can I encrypt the mnemonic and store it in local storage, and then decrypt it?

How can I do the transaction safely?

Here I have [tried the process](https://github.com/amiyatulu/seed_encrypt) where salt for password and iv are stored in local storage, and also encrypted seed is stored in local storage.

```rust
use std::fmt::format;
use libaes::Cipher;
use scrypt::{scrypt, Params, Scrypt};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_json;

use password_hash::{rand_core::OsRng, PasswordHash, PasswordHasher, PasswordVerifier, SaltString};

pub fn generate_hash_and_verify(passwordstring: String) -> String  {
    let password = passwordstring.as_bytes();
    let salt = SaltString::generate(&mut OsRng); 
    println!("salt: {}", salt);
    let password_hash = Scrypt.hash_password(password, &salt).unwrap().to_string();
    let parsed_hash = PasswordHash::new(&password_hash).unwrap();
    assert!(Scrypt.verify_password(password, &parsed_hash).is_ok());
    let salt_string = format!("{}", salt); // Store the salt in local storage.
    salt_string
    
}

pub fn already_used_salt(passwordstring: String, salt_string: String) -> String {
    let salt_str: &str = &salt_string[..];
    let salt = SaltString::new(salt_str).unwrap();
    let password = passwordstring.as_bytes();

    let password_hash = Scrypt.hash_password(password, &salt).unwrap().to_string();
    let parsed_hash = PasswordHash::new(&password_hash).unwrap();
    assert!(Scrypt.verify_password(password, &parsed_hash).is_ok());
    password_hash
}

pub fn encrypt_seed(password_hash: String, seed: String) -> (Vec<u8>, String) {
    let iv_salt = SaltString::generate(&mut OsRng);
    let iv_salt_string = format!("{}", iv_salt); 
    let iv_salt_string_clone = iv_salt_string.clone(); // Store iv salt in local storage
    let iv_salt_bytes = iv_salt_string.into_bytes();
    // println!("iv_salt_bytes len: {}", iv_salt_bytes.len());
    // println!("iv_salt_bytes: {:?}", iv_salt_bytes);
    let iv: &[u8; 16] = &iv_salt_bytes[0..16].try_into().unwrap();
    // println!("iv: {:?}", iv);
    let my_key_bytes = password_hash.into_bytes();
    // println!("my_key_bytes: {:?}", my_key_bytes);
    let my_key: &[u8; 16] = &my_key_bytes[0..16].try_into().unwrap();
    // println!("my_key_bytes: {:?}", my_key);

    let cipher = Cipher::new_128(my_key);

    // Encryption
    let encrypted = cipher.cbc_encrypt(iv, seed.as_bytes()); // Store in local storate
    // println!("{:?}", encrypted); 

    // Decryption
    let decrypted = cipher.cbc_decrypt(iv, &encrypted[..]);
    let seed = String::from_utf8(decrypted).unwrap();
    // println!("{}", seed);
    (encrypted, iv_salt_string_clone)

}

pub fn decrypt_seed(password: String, seed: String) {
     
    let salt_str = generate_hash_and_verify(password.clone());
    let password_hash = already_used_salt(password, salt_str);
    let (encrypted, iv_salt_string) = encrypt_seed(password_hash.clone(), seed);
    let iv_salt_bytes = iv_salt_string.into_bytes();
    let iv: &[u8; 16] = &iv_salt_bytes[0..16].try_into().unwrap();
    let my_key_bytes = password_hash.into_bytes();
    let my_key: &[u8; 16] = &my_key_bytes[0..16].try_into().unwrap();
    let cipher = Cipher::new_128(my_key);
    let decrypted = cipher.cbc_decrypt(iv, &encrypted[..]);
    let seed = String::from_utf8(decrypted).unwrap();
    println!("{}", seed);


}
fn main() {
    let seed = "caution juice atom organ advance problem want pledge someone senior holiday very"
        .to_owned();
    decrypt_seed("passwordubiqutous".to_string(), seed)  

}
```

There are packages too to encrypt messages:
https://docs.rs/pwbox/latest/pwbox/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The questions you pose are more general in scope really; if you want to store anything private in local storage, a good bet is probably to find a good secure symmetric encryption algorithm (maybe aes256?) to encrypt the information first before putting it into local storage, and then requiring the same (strong) password to decrypt the information into memory when you need to make use of it. With that approach, you don't need to store a hashed password or anything like that (I'm not sure why you would offhand); you just use the user submitted password to decrypt and encrypt as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Be extremely careful when store something sensitive in Local Storage.

I suggest you take a look into what Metamask is doing to store this data.

They take the seed phrase and all accounts data bundled together, encrypted with an encryption key generated from the user password.

You can check your encrypted data:

```
chrome.storage.local.get('data', result => {
   var vault = result.data.KeyringController.vault
   console.log(vault)
})
```

And it decrypts it with the [Vault Decryptor](https://github.com/MetaMask/vault-decryptor).

Check the full article about [How to recover your Secret Recovery Phrase](https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018766351-How-to-use-the-Vault-Decryptor-with-the-MetaMask-Vault-Data)